# regular expression and forward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i'm searching for keywords in a string via a regular expression. It works fine for all keywords, exept one which contains a forward slash in it:  "time/emit" .

Even using `preg_quote($find,'/')`, which escapes it, i still get the message:

```
Unknown modifier 't' in /frontend.functions.php  on line 71
```

If i print the find pattern, it shows `/time\\/emit/` . Without preg_quote, it shows `/time/emit/`  and both return the same error message.

Any bit of knowledge would be useful.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try to begin and end your regular expression with different sign than /

I personally use `

I've seen people using #

I think most chars are good. You can read more about it here: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Like this:

```
 preg_match('#time/emit#', $subject);  // instead of /time/emit/
```

To put it another way: Your `$find` variable should contain rather #time/emit# than /time/emit/

Comment: Elegant solution that solved all of my headaches with the slash character.

Answer (score 4):

looks like you have something already escaping it..

```
preg_quote('time/emit') // returns time\/emit
preg_quote('time\/emit') // returns time\\/emit
```

as a hack you could simply do:

```
preg_quote(stripslashes($find)) // will return time\/emit
```

Answer (score 0):

bit of code?

the the 'regex' for that particular term should look something like '/time/emit/'. With a set of keywords there may be a more efficient method so seeing what you are doing would be good.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$a="Hello////////"; 
$b=str_replace($a,"//","/");
echo $b;
```